# Modulo question: $(\operatorname{rand}[0,n-1]+\operatorname{rand}[0,n-1]+\cdots+) \pmod n$?

Tags: probability, modular-arithmetic

I have a problem: There are $i$ betters, each choose a random value between [$0$ and $n-1$]

Then we add all the $i$ numbers and we do (mod $n$)

$$\text{Final number}= (\operatorname{rand}[0,n-1]+\operatorname{rand}[0,n-1]+\cdots+) \pmod n$$

Does the final number has the same odds to fall on every number in $[0 , n-1]$ or does it has more chance to fall on the first numbers of the range ($0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,\ldots$ etc)

Comment: Sure: For independent uniformly distributed random variables $X, Y$ on $\mathbb{Z}_n$, we have $P(X + Y = m) = \int P(X = t) P(Y = m - t)\, dt = 1/n$.

Comment: What does it mean? do I have equal chance to fall on every number in the range so?

Comment: What does what mean?

Comment: What's the good answer: can the final number be any number  in $[0,n-1]$ with the same chance ? or will it be more likely the first numbers of that range?

Comment: Did you not read what I wrote, or was it unclear?

Comment: Yes but I don't understand it, I don't have a good level in mathematics and I don't know the meaning of it

Comment: When you say $[0,n-1]$, do you actually mean the integers in that range?

Comment: @peterwhy yes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6...n-1

Comment: Then you should be able to prove by induction on $i$ that all number in that range has the same probability.

Comment: Thank you peterwhy, that's what I needed to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_j$ denote the $j$-th number, chosen uniformly at random from the range of integers $[0, n-1]$.  We are interested in the quantity

$$
Y=\sum_{j=1}^i X_j\mod n
$$

Suppose we have already picked all but the last number.  So we have $X_1,\dots,X_{i-1}$, and if we add these numbers together and take the result modulo $n$, we will end up with an integer $z$ between $0$ and $n-1$.  Now pick the last number $X_i$ and add it to $z$.  *Whatever the value of $z$*, the quantity $Y=z+X_i\mod n$ takes each value between $0$ and $n-1$ with equal probability.  Can you see why?

Since this is the case for every value that $z$ could possibly take, we deduce that $Y$ takes each value between $0$ and $n-1$ with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number from the $k$th better be $X_k \sim U(0,n-1)$, and the final number be $Y_k$ for the first $k$ betters.

For $i = 1$, $Y_1 = X_1 \sim U(0,n-1)$, hence statement is true.

Assume statement is true for some $i\in\mathbb N$, $Y_i\sim U(0,n-1)$.

Consider the case with $i+1$ betters:

$$\begin{align*}
Y_{i+1}&=(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_i+Y_{X+1})\bmod n\\
&= ((X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_i)\bmod n + X_{i+1})\bmod n\\
&= (Y_i + X_{i+1})\bmod n
\end{align*}$$

Since $X_{i+1}\sim Y_i \sim U(0,n-1)$, the pre-mod sum $(X_{i+1}+Y_i)$ takes any integer with equal probability in the range from $Y_i$ to $(Y_i+n-1)$ given $Y_i$, and the modded sum takes any integer between $0$ to $n-1$ inclusive given $Y_i$. So the mod of their sum also follows $U(0,n-1)$.